# How do I change drupal_core_path to /public instead of /web?

Tags: virtual-machine

I use [Drupal VM](https://www.drupalvm.com) and I have to change the folder from *{{ drupal_composer_install_dir }}/web* to *{{ drupal_composer_install_dir }}/public*.

When I do it and I run `vagrant up`, I get this error.

> An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv.
>   The error was: OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/www/jb-inflatables/public'
>   fatal: [jb-inflatables]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed_when_result": true, "module_stderr": "Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File \"/home/vagrant/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1560461183.6-73909259621121/AnsiballZ_command.py\", line 114, in `<module>`
>   _ansiballz_main()
>   File "/home/vagrant/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1560461183.6-73909259621121/AnsiballZ_command.py", line 106, in _ansiballz_main
>   invoke_module(zipped_mod, temp_path, ANSIBALLZ_PARAMS)
>   File "/home/vagrant/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1560461183.6-73909259621121/AnsiballZ_command.py\", line 49, in invoke_module
>   imp.load_module('**main**', mod, module, MOD_DESC)
>   File "/tmp/ansible_command_payload_KaNSZF/**main**.py", line 327, in
>   `<module>`
>   File "/tmp/ansible_command_payload_KaNSZF/**main**.py", line 263, in main
>   OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/www/jb-inflatables/public', "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE See stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 1

How do I have to change the config.yml file so that Drupal is installed in /public instead of /web?

Comment: What error are you getting? Did you happen to make those changes in your `config.yml` after running `vagrant up`? You may need to run `vagrant destroy && vagrant up` and let it rebuild. Or maybe just `vagrant provision`. You should just need `drupal_core_path: "/your/path/to/public"` in your `config.yml` to override the `default.config.yml` directory.

Comment: @Prestosaurus yes I did first `vagrant destroy` and then removed all the files etc and then I did `vagrant up` again. I just changed /web to /public? I added the error above...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default `drupal-vm setup` use [drupal-composer/drupal-project](https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project) which use `/web` directory.

If you need another directory for your dependencies (e.g. `/public_html`, `public`), you have to make a composer setup (`composer init`) without drupal-composer/drupal-project. See [this page](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/using-composer/using-composer-to-install-drupal-and-manage-dependencies) for more information.

Then you can choose the folder structure yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to create a symbolic link to web called public.
`ln -s web public`
Your server will find the contents of web/ inside of public/ and vagrant will find what it needs in web.